# Количество раз, которое шарик ударился об стену

Tags: javascript, функции, counter

Не понимаю, почему не работает функция counter, которую я вызываю в тот момент, когда шарик ударяется о правую стенку. От функции я ожидаю, что она будет считать количество ударов и выводить его в маленький квадратик слева. Но она вообще себя никак не проявляет.

```js
    var ballH={
        posX : 30,
        posY : 30,
        speedX : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
        speedY : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
        width : 50,
        height: 50,

        update : function() {
            var ballElem=document.getElementById('IBall');
            ballElem.style.left=this.posX+"px";
            ballElem.style.top=this.posY+"px";
        }
    };

    var areaH={
        width : 400,
        height : 300
    };

    function start() {
        // плавное движение - от 25 кадр/сек
        setInterval(tick,40);
    }

    function counter(){
        let greenCount = document.getElementById('CountG');
        let count = 1;
        return function () {
            greenCount.innerHTML = +count;
            return count++;
        }
    }

    function tick() {

        ballH.posX+=ballH.speedX;
        // вылетел ли мяч правее стены?
        if ( ballH.posX+ballH.width>areaH.width ) {
            ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
            ballH.posX=areaH.width-ballH.width;
            counter();
        }
        // вылетел ли мяч левее стены?
        if ( ballH.posX<0 ) {
            ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
            ballH.posX=0;
        }

        ballH.posY+=ballH.speedY;
        // вылетел ли мяч ниже пола?
        if ( ballH.posY+ballH.height>areaH.height ) {
            ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
            ballH.posY=areaH.height-ballH.height;
        }
        // вылетел ли мяч выше потолка?
        if ( ballH.posY<0 ) {
            ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
            ballH.posY=0;
        }

        ballH.update();
    }

    ballH.update();
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Пуск!' onclick='start()'>
<div style = 'width:30px;height:30px;border:solid 2px #ccc6c6; color:#494949; font-size:20px;' id="CountG"></div>
<br /><br />
<div style='width: 400px; height: 300px;
    border: solid blue 1px; position: relative'>
    <div  id='IBall'
          style='position: absolute;width:40px;height:40px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вероятно, последнюю строчку нужно заменить на `start()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут отдельная функция совсем не обязательна, но если сильно хочется, она будет выглядеть так:

```js
var count = 0; // переменная-счетчик объявляется отдельно от функции, один раз.
function counter(){
    count ++; // При каждом вызове увеличивается на единицу, и всё.
    document.getElementById('CountG').innerText = count;

    //Эти две строчки можно было просто вот в таком виде добавить под if, без функции
}



var ballH={
    posX : 30,
    posY : 30,
    speedX : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
    speedY : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
    width : 50,
    height: 50,

    update : function() {
        var ballElem=document.getElementById('IBall');
        ballElem.style.left=this.posX+"px";
        ballElem.style.top=this.posY+"px";
    }
};

var areaH={
    width : 400,
    height : 300
};

function start() {
    // плавное движение - от 25 кадр/сек
    setInterval(tick,40);
}

function tick() {

    ballH.posX+=ballH.speedX;
    // вылетел ли мяч правее стены?
    if ( ballH.posX+ballH.width>areaH.width ) {
        ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
        ballH.posX=areaH.width-ballH.width;
        counter();
    }
    // вылетел ли мяч левее стены?
    if ( ballH.posX<0 ) {
        ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
        ballH.posX=0;
    }

    ballH.posY+=ballH.speedY;
    // вылетел ли мяч ниже пола?
    if ( ballH.posY+ballH.height>areaH.height ) {
        ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
        ballH.posY=areaH.height-ballH.height;
    }
    // вылетел ли мяч выше потолка?
    if ( ballH.posY<0 ) {
        ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
        ballH.posY=0;
    }

    ballH.update();
}

ballH.update();
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Пуск!' onclick='start()'>
<div style = 'width:30px;height:30px;border:solid 2px #ccc6c6; color:#494949; font-size:20px;' id="CountG"></div>
<br /><br />
<div style='width: 400px; height: 300px;
    border: solid blue 1px; position: relative'>
    <div  id='IBall'
          style='position: absolute;width:40px;height:40px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если захочется сделать кнопку перезапуска, в нем надо будет добавить `count = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

У Вас функция `counter` создает другую функцию, которую уже необходимо вызывать, я вынес ее в переменную  `count`

```
let count = counter();
```

И внутри проверки столкновения уже вызываю эту вложенную функцию, ссылка на которую сохранена в переменную `count`

```js
let count = counter();

var ballH={
        posX : 30,
        posY : 30,
        speedX : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
        speedY : Math.random()*(20 + 10) - 10,
        width : 50,
        height: 50,

        update : function() {
            var ballElem=document.getElementById('IBall');
            ballElem.style.left=this.posX+"px";
            ballElem.style.top=this.posY+"px";
        }
    };

    var areaH={
        width : 400,
        height : 300
    };

    function start() {
        // плавное движение - от 25 кадр/сек
        setInterval(tick,40);
    }

    function counter(){
        let greenCount = document.getElementById('CountG');
        let count = 1;
        return function () {
            greenCount.innerHTML = +count;
            return count++;
        }
    }



    function tick() {

        ballH.posX+=ballH.speedX;
        // вылетел ли мяч правее стены?
        if ( ballH.posX+ballH.width>areaH.width ) {
            ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
            ballH.posX=areaH.width-ballH.width;
            count();
        }
        // вылетел ли мяч левее стены?
        if ( ballH.posX<0 ) {
            ballH.speedX=-ballH.speedX;
            ballH.posX=0;
        }

        ballH.posY+=ballH.speedY;
        // вылетел ли мяч ниже пола?
        if ( ballH.posY+ballH.height>areaH.height ) {
            ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
            ballH.posY=areaH.height-ballH.height;
        }
        // вылетел ли мяч выше потолка?
        if ( ballH.posY<0 ) {
            ballH.speedY=-ballH.speedY;
            ballH.posY=0;
        }

        ballH.update();
    }

    ballH.update();
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Пуск!' onclick='start()'>
<div style = 'width:30px;height:30px;border:solid 2px #ccc6c6; color:#494949; font-size:20px;' id="CountG"></div>
<br /><br />
<div style='width: 400px; height: 300px;
    border: solid blue 1px; position: relative'>
    <div  id='IBall'
          style='position: absolute;width:40px;height:40px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%'>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: и про 25 fps это спорное утверждение